# nodejs Regex to delete every new line character that comes after a space

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Given a string like:

```
"hello\n          \n            my dog is red\n          \n          and\n          stripey\n          \n            \n            with spots\n"
```

I want this:

```
"hello\n                      my dog is red\n                    and\n          stripey\n                                  with spots\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace using this regex,

```
/^[ \t]*\n/mg
```

with empty string, where `^[ \t]*` matches one or more space or tab right from beginning of line till `\n` and removes it.

Check this JS demo.

```js
var s = 'hello\n          \n            my dog is red\n          \n          and\n          stripey\n          \n            \n            with spots\n';
console.log("Before: " + s)
console.log("After: " + s.replace(/^[ \t]*\n/mg, ''))
```

Comment: You could also use `\s` instead of `[ \t]` to match any whitespace characters and not just spaces and tabs

Comment: @Linschlager: Yes, `\s` will work too.